# using forecast values from a univariate model as Input to linear regression?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, linear-regression, multi-output

I have weekly time series data for the last 2 years with variables  `"week", "marketing_spend", "web_traffic", and "revenue"` Now I need to forecast `"potential_web_traiffc" & "potential_revenue"` for the next `12 weeks` unfortunately, I don't know the `"marketing_spend"` for next 12 weeks. I am asked to forecast potential costs and based on it forecast other outputs.

I am a little confused, I am planning to run a univariate model to get the `"marketing_spend"` for the next 12 weeks and then run a linear regression to get `"potential_web_traiffc"` and then run another linear regression to get `"potential_revenue"`

I know it doesn't sound right but can someone guide me on what could be the right approach?
This is out dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a date range from 2021-01-07 to 2022-12-29 (Thursdays only)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-07', end='2022-12-29', freq='W-THU')

# Create a DataFrame with random data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': dates,
    'cost': np.random.uniform(low=100000, high=1500000, size=len(dates)).astype(int),
})
# Calculate the revenue column based on the cost and traffic columns
data['traffic'] = (data['cost']  * 2.5).round().astype(int)
data['revenue'] = (data['cost']  * 2).round().astype(int)
# Create new columns for week, month, and year
data['week'] = data['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
data['month'] = data['date'].dt.month
data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year

df = data
df
```

The model I am using to forecast cost is as follows

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Convert date column to datetime format and set as index
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Create a new data frame with only the 'cost' column
cost_df = df[['cost']]

# Split data into train and test sets
train_data = cost_df.iloc[:-12]
test_data = cost_df.iloc[-12:]

# Convert index to numerical values
train_data['numeric_index'] = range(len(train_data.index))

# Build and fit the model using OLS regression
model = sm.OLS(train_data['cost'], sm.add_constant(train_data['numeric_index'])).fit()

# Create a new dataframe for the next 12 weeks
next_weeks = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df.index[-1]+pd.Timedelta(days=1), periods=12, freq='W-THU'), columns=['date'])
next_weeks['week'] = next_weeks['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
next_weeks['month'] = next_weeks['date'].dt.month
next_weeks['year'] = next_weeks['date'].dt.year

# Convert index to numerical values
next_weeks['numeric_index'] = range(len(train_data.index), len(train_data.index) + len(next_weeks))

# Use the model to make predictions for the next 12 weeks
next_weeks['cost'] = model.predict(sm.add_constant(next_weeks['numeric_index']))

# Print the data frame with the forecasted cost for the next 12 weeks
print(next_weeks)
```

now I am using the next_weeks dataframe as test set and forecasting traffic and revenue based on it

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train = df[['week', 'month', 'cost']]
y_train = df[['traffic', 'revenue']]
X_test = next_weeks[['week', 'month', 'cost']]

# Train a random forest regressor as a multioutput regressor
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42))
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Use the model to make predictions for the next 12 weeks
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

# Add the predicted traffic and revenue columns to the next_weeks dataframe
next_weeks[['traffic', 'revenue']] = np.round(y_pred).astype(int)

print(next_weeks)
```

can someone please help me find a better solution or guide me towards the correct approach to such a problem? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly fine! But instead of estimating the marketing expenditure univariately, you could try to build another regression model to estimate it using other parameters as well.